# debug or release apk not running on device/emulator. React native with hermes (rn-cli app with expo modules)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-hermes

I created an RN application and it is not running on the device when I create an APK (debug or release)

It gives the following error (used flipper to get the logs)[image]

It works when using the "npx react-native run-android", however not when I create a standalone apk.

Following is the package json dependencies:

[image]

if anyone can help me with how should I narrow down the issue or how I should proceed with resolving this. It would be great help

Comment: Maybe it's something related with the bundler? I need more information. How you compile the apk?

Comment: I follow this article to generate apk: https://medium.com/geekculture/react-native-generate-apk-debug-and-release-apk-4e9981a2ea51

Comment: Try openning the Android folder on Android Studio and creating the apk there. You can compile debug and release –

Comment: Will do that and update you if it works

Comment: Tried building with the Android studio, didn't work